# How to parse for tags with '+' in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm getting a "nothing to repeat" error when I try to compile this:

```
search = re.compile(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9])(%s)([^a-zA-Z0-9])' % '+test', re.I)
```

The problem is the '+' sign.  How should I handle that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
re.compile(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9])(%s)([^a-zA-Z0-9])' % '\+test', re.I)
```

The "+" is the "repeat at least once" quantifier in regular expressions. It must follow something that is repeatable, or it must be escaped if you want to match a literal "+".

Better is this, if you want to build your regex dynamically.

```
re.compile(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9])(%s)([^a-zA-Z0-9])' % re.escape('+test'), re.I)
```

Comment: Both so quick of the mark!  
An this seems to work ok where it's a variable
tag = '+test' (or tag='test')
search = re.compile(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9])(%s)([^a-zA-Z0-9])' % r'\%s' % tag, re.I)

Thank you both.

Answer (score 8):

Escape the plus:

```
r'\+test'
```

The plus has a special meaning in regexes (meaning "match the previous once or several times"). Since in your regex it appears after an open paren, there is no "previous" to match repeatedly.